# Is it correct to use 'if' in Prolog this way?

Tags: if-statement, prolog, conditional-statements

Recently I started to learn logic programming and using Prolog, and a few days ago I found out that conditional statements can be used in Prolog as well.
I am wondering, if I have a predicate that must be called in both cases, is it correct to write the code this way:

```
process(args) :-
    (condition -> process_args1; process_args2),
    predicateCalledAnyway.
```

instead of calling it in both cases, like this:

```
process(args) :-
    (condition -> process_args1, predicateCalledAnyway; process_args2, predicateCalledAnyway).
```

Is there any difference? If yes, what and why? For me it seems the code produces the same results in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These forms to write the code are **equivalent**.

The first version is shorter and makes it easier to spot the common parts.

However, note the more fundamental problems that are inherent to *both* versions: `(->)/2` impurely *commits* to the *first solution* of the condition, and in general, `( Cond -> Then ; Else )` is only sound if `Cond` is sufficiently instantiated.

For example:

```
?- ( member(X, [a,b,c]) -> false ; true ).
false.
```

Yet, *adding a constraint* suddenly makes this succeed:

```
?- X = d, ( member(X, [a,b,c]) -> false ; true ).
X = d.
```

Declaratively, we expect that *adding* a constraint leads to a *specialization*, not a *generalization* of the program!

Therefore, use `(->)/2` with extreme caution: In general, it will break one of the most valuable properties of your Prolog programs, namely their **relational nature** that allows you to use your predicates in multiple directions and modes.

If at all possible, use either pure Prolog clauses, or the pure `if_/3` predicate. See also the related constructs `(*->)/2` and `if/3` (in SICStus).